# Yii2 Http cache expiress return not match with config

Tags: yii2

i set http cache for image. And has cache control header is public, max-age=3600

Code:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
                'only' => ['index'],
                //'cacheControlHeader' => 'public, max-age=3600',
                //'sessionCacheLimiter' => 'public',
                'lastModified' => function ($action, $params) {
                    /*Todo clear cache*/
                    $cacheKey = CACHE_IMAGE_FLAG;
                    $data = systemCache()->get($cacheKey);
                    /*Clear cache taget 1 hour */
                    if ($data === false) {
                        systemCache()->set($cacheKey, time(), TimeHelper::SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR);
                    }
                    return $data;
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
```

and result return Expires:Wed, 04 Oct 2017 04:05:23 GMT. So have problem with seting Http cache. and my setting is ok?.

[image]

Comment: What is `systemCache()` and where do you get it from? Also what is this constant `CACHE_IMAGE_FLAG`?

Comment: systemCache() is helper for get Yii2 file cache. and CACHE_IMAGE_FLAG is String, that not important. And please show demo here http://cubic1.jp/image/view?path=/1/WR2KxVdK0OC81WbYqrC_1471332283.jpg&w=508&h=207&fit=crop

Comment: systemCache()  return Yii::$app->cache

Comment: Config looks ok. Maybe your Apache server is overriding this header and setting it to default `never-expire` value which is one year in the future?

Comment: @Bizley, i using Share hosting, so i will check again if has problem.

Comment: BTW - you set `'only' => ['index'],` but route looks like using `view` action and not `index` - are you sure this behavior is applied?

Comment: I see, i override by url manager ['pattern'=>'image/view', 'route'=>'image/index'],